# functions.php file doesn't work in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a theme by myself in wordpress. But suddenly my functions.php file stop to work. I am enqueuing a stylesheet file. First time it worked. But now its not working. whats wrong with it?  (I am new in wordpress) My code is

```
<?php

function get_external_files(){

wp_enqueue_style('style', 'get_stylesheet_uri()');

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_external_files');
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from `get_stylesheet_uri()` and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put `get_stylesheet_uri()` inside quotes `''` turning it into a string instead of a function call... This should work:

```
<?php
function get_external_files(){

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_external_files');
```